# Are the elements in a std::map guaranteed to be ordered?

Tags: c++, stl

Is this just an implementation side effect (red-black tree) or the order is guaranteed by the c++ standard?

Comment: The class is std::map, not stl::map.

Comment: No, the implementation (red-black tree, but not necessarily) is chosen to meet the order requirement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ordered iteration is not an implementation detail; it is guaranteed by the C++ standard.  It is a fundamental property of all associative containers (C++03 §23.1.2/9):

> The fundamental property of iterators of associative containers is that they iterate through the containers in the non-descending order of keys where non-descending is defined by the comparison that was used to construct them.  For any two dereferenceable iterators `i` and `j` such that distance from `i` to `j` is positive,
>
> ```
>     value_comp(*j, *i) == false
> ```

`value_comp` is the comparator with which the map was constructed (by default, it is `std::less<T>`).

Comment: @rlbond:  True.  However, C++03 has no unordered associative containers and in C++0x they are categorized separately ("associative containers" are separate from "unordered associative containers").

Answer (score 4):

§23.1.2/2:

> Each associative container is
>   parameterized on `Key` and an ordering
>   relation `Compare` that induces a strict
>   weak ordering (25.3) on elements of
>   `Key`. … The object of type `Compare` is
>   called the comparison object of a
>   container. This comparison object
>   may be a pointer to function or an
>   object of a type with an appropriate
>   function call operator.

The default `Compare` object is the less-than function `std::less<Key>`.

The ordering is a property of the function. It's a requirement, not a side effect.

*Sorting* the objects is a side effect. 23.1.2/10 and 23.1.2/9 (quoted by James) guarantee that map/set and multimap/multiset have increasing/non-decreasing keys, respectively, over the sequence from `begin` to `end`.

Answer (score 2):

It's guaranteed by the c++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

Guaranteed. If you want something that's not constrained by this try boost::unordered_map<>

Comment: Or, similarly, `std::tr1::unordered_map<>'.